# how do i count up in a table with data from other table? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem with a trigger i need to make i show you what i have and then what the question is.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `ISBN` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Version` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ISBN`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookauthor` (
  `ISBN` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  `BSN` int(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ISBN`,`BSN`),
  KEY `bookauthor_ibfk_2` (`BSN`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publisher` (
  `name` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `sales volume` double NOT NULL,
  `logo` longblob NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` int(48) NOT NULL,
  `amount_sold` int(48) NOT NULL
);
```

my question is,
i want to have a trigger that updates sales volume in the publisher table with the sales volume made when the sales table is updated. this needs to happen on a certain publisher and the trigger needs something like (amount_sold * price) but i have no clue on how to do this :(

Comment: What happens if `book` gets updated?

Comment: nothing yet happens when book gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER
        trg_sales_ai
AFTER INSERT
ON      sales
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        UPDATE  publisher p
        CROSS JOIN
                book b
        SET     p.`sales volume` = p.`sales volume` + NEW.amount_sold * b.price
        WHERE   p.name = NEW.publisher
                AND b.ISBN = NEW.isbn
END;
```

Comment: @user3541687: if the answer helped you, please mark it selected (tick the green checkbox under the vote count)

Comment: @user3541687: check the separator. I didn't check the syntax, though, so it might require some polishing.

Comment: what needs to be sepperated with a seperator than?? because there is nothing with a double result. or do i not get the function of the seperator now?

Comment: @user3541687: use something other than semicolon for query separator on your `MySQL` client.